# Accessing html elements from a div tree with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to access **title** value from some **img** elements but these elements are deeply implemented in a div tree and after that into some tables.
 
Let me explain why I need them:
I use a portal where I have information regarding circuits from a network. This portal contains some locations with a few rows (2-3 usually -> circuits for that location). Each row starts with an img element and it can have a few values on **title** attribute. If the title value is != "No alarms" then I have to take all data from that row and I want to show them via a pop up notification on the bottom right corner near clock.
Below you have a screenshot for how are the html elements organized (for all locations).
http://imageshack.com/a/img661/962/ErjQOt.png
Below you have a screenshot for how is a location organized:
http://imageshack.com/a/img661/7453/QAP5oM.png

If title attribute == "Warning", for example, I have to take the data from the next td's in the same table. Each td has another div without id. Firsts 2 td's on each table have another element inside div: *img* on first one and *a href* on the second one.
I'm drawing the tree to show you exactly how are the html elements organized.

```
<table class="x-grid3-row-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td> <!--first td, this contains div->img-->
          <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0">
             <img .... title="No alarms">
          </div>
       </td>
       <td> <!--second td, this contains div->a href-->
          <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1">
             <a href...>
          </div>
       </td>
       <td> <!--3rd td, this contains div->string:Text1-->
          <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-2">Text1</div>
       </td>
       <td> <!--4th td, this contains div->string:Text2-->
          <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-2">Text2</div>
       </td>
       ...
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Location-1 has 3 circuits, this means 3 tables. The above table is inserted in a div (*div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-first"* from screenshot2). There are 2 more tables after this one on another div's (*div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-alt"* & *div class="x-grid3-row"* from screenshot2) and I have to check the title attribute for each table.

Now my question is how to get the *title* attribute from each table on the same location? and if the title is != "No alarms" how can I get data from the next td's in that table?

Maybe I can use a loop for all 12 locations or maybe I can get them one by one. This is no big deal because there are only 12 locations but the nasty thing is inside each location to get info from each circuit.

I think there should be a syntax like this to reach each html elements and to get the right value.

```
var title = $('#ext-gen15-gp-location-1-bd table[0] td[0] img').attr('title');
var title = $('#ext-gen15-gp-location-1-bd table[0] td[1] div[0]').attr('innerHTML');
....
var title = $('#ext-gen15-gp-location-1-bd table[1] td[0] img').attr('title');
var title = $('#ext-gen15-gp-location-1-bd table[1] td[1] div[0]').attr('innerHTML');
...
var title = $('#ext-gen15-gp-location-9-bd table[0] td[0] img').attr('title');
var title = $('#ext-gen15-gp-location-9-bd table[0] td[1] div[0]').attr('innerHTML');
...
```

...and so on. I'm sure that this syntax is not correct but I think there should be a way to get that data.

I hope that now is explained better then the first time.
EDIT
Guys, thank you very much. You help me a lot. Your codes are working.
Anyway, I just want to ask you something else. 
After 3 minutes the whole table is refreshing and I can't find a way to reload the function after that. When the content is refreshing, div **ext-gen24** remains empty and after that is refilled with the content:
When is refreshing:

```
<div class="x-grid3-body" style="width: 1877px;" id="ext-gen24"></div>
```

After refresh is completed

```
<div class="x-grid3-body" style="width: 1877px;" id="ext-gen24">content</div>
```

Can you help me with a function you think it should work in this case ?

Comment: `$("#div")` looks like jQuery- are you using it?

Comment: Yes this is JQuery. but I used also:    document.getElementById("mdiv").style.background = "red";

Comment: What do you mean "at id `ext-gen15-gp-location-AMSTERDAM5999` it stops working"? Can you post the selector / javascript you are using to test? Something similar to `$('#ext-gen15-gp-location-AMSTERDAM5999-bd table img')` should do the job, assuming you have set unique ids (which you really really should).

Comment: I used `document.getElementById("ext-gen15-gp-location-AMSTERDAM5999-bd").style.background = "red"`and that field did change its color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need loop through multiple stages of the html: groups, tables, and columns:

```
var groups = $('.x-grid-group-body'); //hopefully all the '#ext-gen15-gp-location-X-bd' div have 'x-grid-group-body' as the class
groups.each(function () {
    var tables = $(this).find('table');
    tables.each(function () {
        var columns = $(this).find('td');
        var image = $(columns[0]).find('img');
        var title = image.attr('title');

        if (title !== 'No alarms') {
            var allInnerHtml = '';
            for (var i = 1; i < columns.length; i++) {
                allInnerHtml += $(columns[i]).find('div').html() + '\n';
            }
            alert(allInnerHtml);
        }
        else {
            //just to show that titles with 'No alarm' are skipped
            alert('skipped');
        }
    });
});
```

See updated **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/usnjgwup/1/)**

Hope that helps! =)

Comment: for the 3 divs, can the ids and class be anything or are they specific? are they all siblings of each other?

Comment: This is working but I need to check them one by one.
As div id="ext-gen15-gp-location-AMSTERDAM5999" there are more than 10 entries, each entry with more than 2 subentries. It would be more easily to add an image but I don't have at least 10 at reputation.

That DIVs contains table and each table contains some td elements with important values so I have to know a way to reach elements one by one after div id="ext-gen15-gp-location-AMSTERDAM5999-bd"

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I have to leave my office (I have to catch a train). I will upload 2-3 imgs when I will arrive at home.

Thanks for understanding and for patient.

Comment: I have added some images. Tell me if you need more info to understand the facts.

Comment: Sorry i haven't forgotten about this. I just haven't had time to look at it and code up a solution.

Comment: I redesigned my main post. I think that now is explained better then the initial one.

Comment: I think I understand better now. do the tables ever have multiple rows?

Comment: i updated my answer to what i think you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

If your Div tree has classes in the same format is now you can use something like this.

```
var title = $('.x-panel-bwrap').find('img').attr('title');
```

Or if the div class dependency is not confirmed, then assuming that img tag will always have a class name starting with 'tick', you can use this.

```
var title = $('img *[class^="tick"]').attr('title');
```

EDIT

Now that you have explained your problem more clearly, i've included a fiddle with the solution you need. Now you will have to expand it to suit your code more closely.
For example if you want to log each location separately, start looping through the locations first and then find tables inside them.
Basically you can use Jquery .find and .each to go through your comeplete html and do whetever you want.

```
var tableList = $('.x-grid3-row-table');
tableList.each(function() {
    var imgTitle = $(this).find('img').attr('title');
    alert(imgTitle);
    if (imgTitle == 'Warning') {
        infoTd = $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)');
        text = infoTd.find('div').text();
        alert(text);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ddu7jd8b/)

Comment: First idea doesn't work. The 2nd one is not applicable because class can be tick_16, err_16, warn_16.

Comment: I redesigned my main post. I think that now is explained better then the initial one.

What do you think, any idea?

Comment: Now its a lot clear. I've edited my answer to include a JS fiddle with the exact solution you need.
We could have used the jquery find and looping through the tables.

Comment: I'll try this tommorow and I'll add my feedback. Thanks